# Why doesn’t this sentence use “will be able to”?

Tags: verbs, usage

I think the future form of can is will be able to, and when using type 1 conditional, we should use future tense in the main clause, but then I think in some cases, “will be able to” sounds weird.

I made up a context like this:

A: Dad told me to move that vase into the warehouse tomorrow. I don’t want to do it. It will ruin my new dress.

B: Alright, **if you find me a wheeled cart, I can do it for you tomorrow.**

I think “will be able to” would sound weird here.

Is it because in this sentence, A finding a wheeled cart for B is an act of exchange for his favor?

B already has the power and the ability to move the vase, but he will only do so for A if she manages to make the work easier by finding him a wheeled cart.

Comment: I'm ok with "will be able to" here, but English often uses the present tense to talk about the near future so "can" is fine. Your question suggests you're an English learner so maybe this is more suited for English Language Learners.

Comment: There is no future form of any verb in English.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing 'weird' about _will be able to_.

Comment: It's quite interesting. Some other native speakers told me:
1. If it rains, we can't go to the park tomorrow. (correct)
2. If you don't come with us, you can't hang out with some really cool people tomorrow night. (wrong)

I don't know why. Shouldn't the rule apply to all?

Comment: Also, I think this one sounds okay, but I don't know why:

A: The bus station will be closed by 19:00. Will you need me to give you a ride?

B: It’s okay. There’s another station down the street. If it stays open, I can still take a bus home tomorrow night. 

I guess I will ask it in the English Learner forum. Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Stuart has already told you that it's OK to use the present tense.  "We can't go to the park tomorrow" and "We won't be able to go..." are both fine.

Comment: @Skywarrior *Shouldn't the rule apply to all?* -- No. There are no "rules" in English, only guidance. Some guidance looks like a rule; it probably isn't.

Comment: 'I will be able to' and even 'I'll be able to' sound more starchy than 'I can' when they're otherwise interchangeable, in just about any conversation. And 'for you' is probably redundant here.

Comment: @DW256 Yes, some linguists say that yet native speakers understand what a future verb means.

Answer (score 1):

Modal auxiliaries are very complex.

Just as every English modal auxiliary verb has at least two meanings (one involving logic and the other social obligation), modal auxiliaries are defective verbs, since they lack inflections like tenses, infinitive forms, and participial forms. These are often necessary, however, so every modal verb also has a corresponding periphrastic construction that **does** have these forms.

Some examples:

- *She **can** do that.* **She canned do that* *She was able to do that*. (ability *can = **be able to***)
- *She **may** do that.* **She mayed do that* *She was allowed to do that*. (deontic *may = **be allowed to***)
- *She **must** do that.* **She musted do that* *She had to do that* (deontic *must = **have to***)

Forget about the future tense; there isn't any. *Will* is just another modal auxiliary verb, like *would, can, could, shall, should, may, might, must,* and sometimes *need* and *dare*. Get the modals straightened out and throw away the textbooks that refer to future tense.

Answer (score 0):

Despite A expressing an inability to do the task without ruining her clothes, B's answer is not about ability, but about *making an offer*.

The verb "can" meaning "be able to" can have the function of *offering/promising to do something*.

> I can carry some of the bags in and it'll be done in half the time.
>
> I can cook dinner tonight if you like.

In both these situations, both the speaker and listener are clearly able to do the task. So the speaker is *offering* to do it for different reasons than lack of ability.

That's the case here. What B really means is something like:

> B: Alright, **I offer to** move the vase tomorrow on the condition you find me a wheeled cart.